# VueJS: Redirecting between two pages

Tags: redirect, vue.js

I use Firebase with VueJS (and VueRouter).

I have a problem with redirecting. I want to redirect between two pages. The first page is used for authentication and the second one for content that should only be visible to logged-in users.

My **state** holds the firebase user key (which will be populated through a mutation, that calls firebase):

```
state: {
  user: { key: null }
}
```

The **authentication** page these lines:

```
beforeCreate() {
  if (this.$store.state.user.key !== null) {
    this.$router.replace('/')
  }
}
```

And the **secret** page these:

```
beforeCreate() {
  if (this.$store.state.user.key === null) {
    this.$router.replace('/new')
  }
}
```

But: the redirect from the authentication page to the secret page doesn't take place.

My Vue-dev-tools show that the user-key is set.

What could be the solution to this problem?

**EDIT:**

This is the mutation that calls Firebase and sets the user-key:

```
updateSession(state) {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      state.user.key = user.uid
    }
  })
}
```

Here is the action:

```
UPDATE_SESSION({ commit }) {
  commit('updateSession')
}
```

I call the action in my root component (App.vue):

```
beforeCreate() {
  this.$store.dispatch('UPDATE_SESSION')
}
```

**EDIT 2**:

Now my routes array:

```
routes: [
  { path: '/', component: Secret },
  { path: '/new', component: Authentication }
]
```

Comment: A call to firebase api to set the user key is an async call, maybe the `beforeCreate()` in your authentication page where you redirect to the secret page is getting called before the user's key is set in the store. So can you show the code of the mutation where you set the user key by making a call to firebase

Comment: You are showing a mutation but dispatching an action in App.vue

Comment: So you secret component is the root url ('/'), is your authentication page a ,login page and after the user logged in you want to redirect him to secret page?

Comment: well you are absolutely right.

Comment: Is it possible, that in the `beforeCreate` your key is null, however later on it will be changed? Then you should try to use a watcher.

Comment: could you explain how to setup a watcher?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Per-Route Guards section of the docs: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

You might want to try something like the below. By putting the beforeEnter guard on the route, you are telling Vue to do that first. The `next` argument tells VueRouter what to do next, and can redirect if needed or continue on to the original route.

```
 beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
  if (this.$store.state.user.key === null) {
    next('/new')
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

You may also want to try using `push` instead of `replace`

Comment: no, this doesn't work. the user key is set and the redirect doesn't take place.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle or codepen? I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: You may also want to try using push instead of replace

Comment: does the "secret" path work if you navigate to it directly? Can you post your router path object where your routes are defined?

Comment: maybe I could use something like a watcher for the user-key??

Answer (score 0):

As per the conversation we had in the comments looks like you require this:

`store.dispatch` can handle Promise returned by the triggered action handler and it also returns Promise. See [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html).

So you can setup the login action to retirn a promise like this:

```
a_logInUser: ({state, commit}, userInput) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userInput.email, userInput.paswword);
        resolve();
    });
}
```

Then in your authentication page where you tale the login input details and click the login button , set this up as the click handler of your login button

```
loginUser(){
    this.$store.dispatch('a_logInUser', {email: this.email, password: this.password})
        .then((result) => {
            this.$router.replace('/');
            }, (err) => {
                // stay on this pageS
                //handle login error                
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Timo you can learn about promises here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and using promises in vuex actions from the link i provided in my answer.

Comment: I still don't really grasp promises, could you provide a small sample in a js fiddle? I would appreciate it !! :D thanks.

Comment: @Timo see https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/1pe0nnm0/ , data is fetched using vue-reource till then loading spinner is shown and after fetch is complete the loding spinner is removed in the promise